# Issues verifying that specific text exists in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I am working on automation using Selenium and I need to verify some text that is on the web page.

This is the text in question:

```
//span[text()='Quantity  > 1000000 OR [Quantity] includes Null')]
```

I have even replaced the spaces with `${nbsp}` and `${space}` both, but it still do not work.

Are there any suggestions for additional characters that I need to escape to be able to run with Selenium?

Comment: Can you add the html that contains the text you're trying to match?

Comment: There is no `includes` function in XPath. What **exactly** are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your Xpath is invalid;

```
//span[text()='Quantity  > 1000000 OR [Quantity] includes Null')]
```

Do you have an extra closing parenthesis?  Should it be;

```
//span[text()='Quantity  > 1000000 OR [Quantity] includes Null']
```

BTW - if you do have xpath issues, I would recommend installing Firebug and Firepath and open the website in Firefox.  This will let tests your identifiers

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a few days ago, and generically what I did was run the Selenium test as a jUnit and plug in an assert for each piece of text that I wanted to find.  Like so:

```
final String pageText = new String(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("BODY")).getText());
assertTrue(pageText.contains("PLACE YOUR TEXT HERE"));
```

This is run with an InternetExplorerDriver as the driver object.  This has done the trick for me.  =)